# Android TableLayout remove padding

Tags: android, android-layout, android-tablelayout

What I'm trying to do is to remove every padding and margin from a `TableLayout`, and display the children buttons tiled.

This is the `activity_main.xml` code

```
<TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".Main"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:baselineAligned="false">

    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="New Button"
            android:id="@+id/button1" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="New Button"
            android:id="@+id/button4" />
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="New Button"
            android:id="@+id/button2" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="New Button"
            android:id="@+id/button3" />
    </TableRow>

</TableLayout>
```

All the paddings are set to 0.

This is what I get:

[image]

And this is what I'm trying to get:

[image]

Comment: you are using fill_parent you should use wrap_content

Comment: what api are you using?

Comment: You are right, however I'm using the API level 14

Comment: Given code snippet works as expected. What are you trying to do?

Comment: My fault, I switched the images. I'm trying to achieve the following: http://i.stack.imgur.com/3JaOT.jpg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both [`TableLayout`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TableLayout.html) and [`TableRow`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TableRow.html) are `LinearLayouts`. So using the [`weight`](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/linear.html#Weight) attribute will give you the desired result:

1. Set `TableLayout's` width and height to `match_parent`
2. Set `layout_height="0dp"` and `layout_weight="0.5"` for the `TableRows` to make them fit 50% of the screen height each;
3. Set each `Button's` height to `match_parent` to fill the row's height, and also set its `layout_width="0dp"` and `layout_weight="0.5"` to fit the row's width equally.

Here is the layout:

```
<TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

<TableRow
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="0.5">

    <Button
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="0.5"
        android:text="New Button"
        android:id="@+id/button1" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="0.5"
        android:text="New Button"
        android:id="@+id/button4" />
</TableRow>

<TableRow
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="0.5">

    <Button
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="0.5"
        android:text="New Button"
        android:id="@+id/button2" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="0.5"
        android:text="New Button"
        android:id="@+id/button3" />
</TableRow>

</TableLayout>
```

And here is how it looks like:

[image]

Comment: I copied your example. It's does not work. buttons have padding

Comment: @Butsaty Without seeing you EXACT layout xml it's hard to tell what "doesn't work". This layout helped to the question owner...Ask a new question and, if you'd like, let me know, - I'll take a look at the question.

Comment: @Butsaty When you downvote, please, explain exactly what was wrong with an answer. Otherwise it might mean that it was you who made use of the answer in a wrong way. Like here, for example, there are no paddings at all, so it must be something else in your code.