# Why is each element in the table row still taking the same amount of space

Tags: android, xml, textview, tablerow

Here is what I am getting when I run my application on my device [image]

The part that I have problems with is the rows - with text, quote, and web. I dynamically inserted those rows into the scroll view at runtime. Here is my xml code that I used for layout inflating

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TableRow xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/stockView"
        android:text="TextView"
        android:layout_weight="2" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/stockQuote"
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:text="@string/get_stock_quote" 
          android:layout_weight="1" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/webStock"
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:text="@string/go_to_website"
          android:layout_weight="1"  />

</TableRow>
```

My question is with this code, why is each element still taking the same amount of space. I know that because I specified the text view's layout_weight to 2, it should take up half of the width with each button taking 1/4 of the total width. I know this isn't bc of weight sum as weight sum by default is 4 in this case. Does anyone know how i can get the text view to take up 1/2 of its parent's width?

Comment: Check my answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26071142/android-ui-default-margin-remove/26071377#26071377

Comment: thanks for trying but that didn't work. That did highlight the fact that all three had the same width

Comment: Along with the weight attribute try setting a view's width to 0.

Comment: Thanks but I dont think that will make a difference. At least thats what I got from this thread. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26072522/what-are-the-default-values-when-you-dont-specify-height-and-width-for-elements

Comment: _"I dont think that will make a difference"_??? Can you explain? This is not what the official docs say about the `weight` attribute. Take a look at [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25633660/android-tablelayout-remove-padding/25635441#25635441) with the references to what `TableLayout`, `TableRow` and `weight` represent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Check this it works..**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TableRow xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="@android:color/transparent" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/stockView"
    android:layout_width="0dip"
    android:text="TextView"
    android:layout_weight="2" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/stockQuote"
    android:layout_width="0dip"
    style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
    android:text="get_stock_quote"
    android:layout_weight="1" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/webStock"
    android:layout_width="0dip"
    style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
    android:text="go_to_website"
    android:layout_weight="1"  />
```

Comment: My original works. Thanks. It was just the preview that was a little off

Comment: can you make your question more clear? the above one is with 0dip of width it work by doing it..  and you can even make your weight values like 50, 25, 25 also..

Answer (score 0):

You should play with layout_span. Try to add android:layout_span="2" to your textview.

[What is the equivalent of "colspan" in an Android TableLayout?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2710793/what-is-the-equivalent-of-colspan-in-an-android-tablelayout)