# Any other attributes other than layout_weight that will make one element take more space than the others?

Tags: android, tablerow, android-layout-weight

This question is based off my other one. [Why is each element in the table row still taking the same amount of space](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26072354/why-is-each-element-in-the-table-row-still-taking-the-same-amount-of-space)

The problem wasn't due to the default margin of buttons or the layout_width attribute. IS there just some property of table row that won't let layout_weight work? If so, is there any other attribute I can use to deal with this issue. I know I cannot use layout_span because that involves two rows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Check this it works..**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TableRow xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="@android:color/transparent" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/stockView"
    android:layout_width="0dip"
    android:text="TextView"
    android:layout_weight="2" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/stockQuote"
    android:layout_width="0dip"
    style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
    android:text="get_stock_quote"
    android:layout_weight="1" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/webStock"
    android:layout_width="0dip"
    style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
    android:text="go_to_website"
    android:layout_weight="1"  />
```

Comment: layout_width:0dip added